# How do I simplify this jquery script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, refactoring

I have an ASP.NET web forms project that I am trying to implement auto-tabbing in. I'm new to jquery, but I found a code snippet online to do auto-tabbing, and I want to use it to autotab multiple groups of textboxes.

For example:

```
Textbox1 -> Textbox2 -> Textbox3

Textbox4 -> Textbox5 -> Textbox6
```

But not:

```
Textbox3 -> Textbox4
```

Hope that makes sense. Anyway, I have the following code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".autotab").keyup(function () {
            if ($(this).attr("maxlength") == $(this).val().length) {
                var index = $(".autotab").index(this);
                var item = $($(".autotab")[++index]);
                if (item.length > 0)
                    item.focus();
            }
        });
        $(".autotab2").keyup(function () {
            if ($(this).attr("maxlength") == $(this).val().length) {
                var index = $(".autotab2").index(this);
                var item = $($(".autotab2")[++index]);
                if (item.length > 0)
                    item.focus();
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<input name="tbOne" type="text" maxlength="3" id="tbOne" class="autotab" />
<input name="tbTwo" type="text" maxlength="3" id="tbTwo" class="autotab" />
<input name="tbThree" type="text" maxlength="4" id="tbThree" class="autotab" />

<input name="tbFour" type="text" maxlength="3" id="tbFour" class="autotab2" />
<input name="tbFive" type="text" maxlength="3" id="tbFive" class="autotab2" />
<input name="tbSix" type="text" maxlength="4" id="tbSix" class="autotab2" />
```

How can I refactor the copy/pasted code into a single function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more general solution, that doesn't require that you use one class per group:

```
// loop through adjacent pairs
$.fn.eachPair = function(f) {
    for(var i = 0, j = 1; j < this.length; i = j++)
        f.call(this[i], this[j]);
}

$.fn.autotab = function() {
    this.eachPair(function(next) {
        // add an event handler to focus the next field
        $(this).keyup(function() {
            if($(this).attr("maxlength") == $(this).val().length)
                $(next).focus();
        });
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".autotab").autotab();
    $(".autotab2").autotab();
});
```

<sup>As a side note, the `$($(".autotab2")[++index])` in your code would have been better written as `$(".autotab2").eq(index + 1)`</sup>

Comment: @user1689607: Very good point. I've completely changed my answer

Comment: You're running into the *"closure in a loop"* problem. Simplest solution would probably be to use `.each()`. return `var els = this; return this.each(function(i,el) { ... });`

Comment: Why not? It gives you the current index, so you could do `var next = els.eq(i + 1);`

Comment: My solution iterates from `[0, 1]` to `[n-2, n-1]`, `.each` goes to `[n-1, n]`

Comment: Your update works too. Just cleaner to use `.each()` IMO. You'll have a silent failure for the last handler, or could be avoided by skipping the handler on the last index. Either way. :) +1

Comment: This isn't working for me, it's not autotabbing. I should mention (and I will update the original post), this is an ASP.NET project, I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Eric It's working now. I mistyped something. Thanks a lot for your help. Now off to read a jquery book so I can understand some of this!

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the element by passing in a selector into .next() - this is assuming you have one class assigned to your inputs only and they are all siblings.

```
// get all inputs with class that start with autotab
$("input[class^=autotab]").keyup(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    // get nextfield with same class
    var nextField = $el.next('.'+$el.attr('class'));
    if($el.attr("maxlength") == $el.val().length){
        // if true - give next field with same class focus
        $el.next().focus();
    }
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JaVaR/

Or if they aren't guaranteed siblings.. you can use .eq() to get current index and increment by one.  This will get the collection of elements that match the current elements class, then get the index of the current to find the next field

```
$("input[class^=autotab]").keyup(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    // gets all inputs with same class
    var $inp = $('.'+$el.attr('class'));
    // gets next input with same class
    var nextField = $inp.eq($inp.index(this)+1);
    if($el.attr("maxlength") == $el.val().length){
        nextField.focus();
    }
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L4MEP/